# Azure credentials have not been set up or have expired

Tags: powershell, azure

I have scheduled a PowerShell script to execute a pipeline in Azure. 
Have generated the login script(ProfileContext.ctx) using Login-AzureRMAccount

Below is the code to schedule:

```
$path = "D:\ProfileContext.ctx"
Import-AzureRmContext -Path $path
$dfn = "salesprod"
$rgn = "sale-dw"
$df=Get-AzureRmDataFactory -ResourceGroupName $rgn -Name $dfn

$ISTstartdate = get-date

#Set Pipeline active period
$UTCstartdate = $ISTstartdate.touniversaltime().addminutes(5)
$UTCenddt = $UTCstartdate.AddHours(5)

$pipelinename = "SalesPipeline"

Set-AzureRmDataFactoryPipelineActivePeriod -ResourceGroupName $rgn -PipelineName $pipelinename -DataFactoryName $dfn -StartDateTime $UTCstartdate -EndDateTime $UTCenddt -Force
```

Above code works fine for 2 or 3 days but then I start getting below issue:

Your Azure credentials have not been set up or have expired, please run Login-AzureRMAccount to set up your Azure credentials.
At D:\RunPipeline.ps1
Below are the version nos:

1. PSVersion - 5.0.10586.117
2. Azure - 4.2.1

Comment: What is your Azure Power Shell version. It seems a known [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/3954) on older version PowerShell.

Comment: Use `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh` to list version.

Comment: I get below after using your command:
4.2.1      Azure

Comment: PS Version:
PSVersion                      5.0.10586.117

Comment: The issue is solved on 4.2.0. The latest version is 4.3.1. I use the version for your scenario, it works for me. If possible, you could install the latest version. Please download it from the [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases).

Comment: Thanks for your time.

Comment: I suggest you could create a service principal to login your subscription. `Add-AzureRmAccount -TenantId $tenantid -ServicePrincipal -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId -Credential $userCredential`. It is more safer. Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal#provide-credentials-through-powershell).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved it by using below work around: This would auto login for me and then I can schedule without a context file:

```
$accountName = "pqr@xyz.com"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "mypwd" -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($accountName, $password)
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $credential
Get-AzureRmResource
```

Comment: It only works on Azure AD account. Microsoft account does not support this method.

Comment: Yes and I was using an Azure AD account to login.

Comment: According to your need, I more like use service principal, it is more safer and not leak my account and password. I add it as an answer. Hope it help more people.

Answer (score 1):

Add Joseph's answer. Your answer only works on Azure AD account, Microsoft account does not support non-interactive login. According to your scenario, I suggest you could use Service Principal, it is more safer and not leak your account information. What is [Service Principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal)?

> When you have an app or script that needs to access resources, you can
>   set up an identity for the app and authenticate the app with its own
>   credentials. This identity is known as a service principal.

You could refer to refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal#create-service-principal-with-password) to create a new service principal and give `Contributor` role. You could use the following command to login your subscription.

```
$subscriptionId=""
$tenantid=""
$clientid=""
$password=""
$userPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
$userCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $clientid, $userPassword
Add-AzureRmAccount -TenantId $tenantid -ServicePrincipal -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId -Credential $userCredential
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across with same issue today but after update Azure PowerShell Modules to the latest version, all good. You can do this while easily using Update-Module or just go ahead and use Install-Module AzureRm -Force.